# Celery consumes all queues

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to achieve a following configuration:

1. Send a message to RabbitMQ.
2. Copy this message to 2 different queues.
3. Run 2 consumers, where each of them would consume from its own queue.

So, I have this to send messages:

```py
def publish_message():
    with app.producer_pool.acquire(block=True) as producer:
        producer.publish(
            body={"TEST": "OK"},
            exchange='myexchange',
            routing_key='mykey',
        )
```

I create my consumers this way:

```py
with app.pool.acquire(block=True) as conn:
    exchange = kombu.Exchange(
        name="myexchange",
        type="direct",
        durable=True,
        channel=conn,
    )
    exchange.declare()
    queue1 = kombu.Queue(
        name="myqueue",
        exchange=exchange,
        routing_key="mykey",
        channel=conn,
        # message_ttl=600,
        # queue_arguments={
        #     "x-queue-type": "classic"
        # },
        durable=True
    )
    queue1.declare()
    queue2 = kombu.Queue(
        name="myotherqueue",
        exchange=exchange,
        routing_key="mykey",
        channel=conn,
        # message_ttl=600,
        # queue_arguments={
        #     "x-queue-type": "classic"
        # },
        durable=True
    )
    queue2.declare()


    class MyConsumer1(bootsteps.ConsumerStep):
        def get_consumers(self, channel):
            return [
                    kombu.Consumer(
                        channel,
                        queues=[queue1],
                        callbacks=[self.handle],
                        accept=["json"]
                )
            ]

        def handle(self, body, message):
            print(f"\n### 1 ###\nBODY: {body}\nCONS: {self.consumers}\n#########\n")
            message.ack()


    class MyConsumer2(bootsteps.ConsumerStep):
        def get_consumers(self, channel):
            return [
                kombu.Consumer(
                    channel,
                    queues=[queue2],
                    callbacks=[self.handle],
                    accept=["json"]
                )
            ]

        def handle(self, body, message):
            print(f"\n### 2 ###\nBODY: {body}\nCONS: {self.consumers}\n#########\n")
            message.ack()


    app.steps["consumer"].add(MyConsumer1)
    app.steps["consumer"].add(MyConsumer2)
```

But when I run worker passing `-Q myqueue` I get this:

```
(venv) ➜  src git:(rabbitmq-experiment) ✗ celery -A settings worker -X myotherqueue --hostname 1@%h
 
 -------------- 1@gonczor v5.0.5 (singularity)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.11.0-37-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31 2021-10-14 19:37:26
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         blacksheeplearns:0x7f5abbbf6d30
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://admin:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[2021-10-14 19:37:27,683: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/gonczor/Projects/Learn Web Dev/learn-web-dev/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:203: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
            leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('''Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory

[2021-10-14 19:37:30,724: WARNING/MainProcess] ### 2 ###
BODY: {'TEST': 'OK'}
CONS: [<Consumer: [<Queue myotherqueue -> <Exchange myexchange(direct) bound to chan:4> -> mykey bound to chan:4>]>]
#########
[2021-10-14 19:37:30,724: WARNING/MainProcess] ### 1 ###
BODY: {'TEST': 'OK'}
CONS: [<Consumer: [<Queue myqueue -> <Exchange myexchange(direct) bound to chan:5> -> mykey bound to chan:5>]>]
#########
^C
worker: Hitting Ctrl+C again will terminate all running tasks!

worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
(venv) ➜  src git:(rabbitmq-experiment) ✗ celery -A settings worker -Q myqueue --hostname 1@%h
 
 -------------- 1@gonczor v5.0.5 (singularity)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.11.0-37-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31 2021-10-14 19:38:37
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         blacksheeplearns:0x7f037539dd30
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://admin:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> myqueue          exchange=myqueue(direct) key=myqueue
                

[2021-10-14 19:38:38,855: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/gonczor/Projects/Learn Web Dev/learn-web-dev/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:203: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
            leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('''Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory

[2021-10-14 19:39:00,574: WARNING/MainProcess] ### 2 ###
BODY: {'TEST': 'OK'}
CONS: [<Consumer: [<Queue myotherqueue -> <Exchange myexchange(direct) bound to chan:4> -> mykey bound to chan:4>]>]
#########
[2021-10-14 19:39:00,574: WARNING/MainProcess] ### 1 ###
BODY: {'TEST': 'OK'}
CONS: [<Consumer: [<Queue myqueue -> <Exchange myexchange(direct) bound to chan:5> -> mykey bound to chan:5>]>]
#########
```

So as you can see single consumer consumes messages from both queues. I've checked that this message is dispatched correctly by turning down the celery worker and I could confirm that the message appeared on 2 queues: `myqueue` and `myotherqueue`.

I'm running this as a part of Django project if this is important.

**EDIT** Maybe someone will find this helpful: when I spawned 2 workers I started getting this error message on random occasions. The routing is also random:

```
[2021-10-14 20:20:29,780: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: {'TEST': 'OK'} (14b)
{content_type:'application/json' content_encoding:'utf-8'
  delivery_info:{'consumer_tag': 'None6', 'delivery_tag': 2, 'redelivered': False, 'exchange': 'myexchange', 'routing_key': 'mykey'} headers={}}
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, your cmd to start 2nd worker has flag "-X myotherqueue".  Should be "-Q myotherqueue".

Comment: I'm starting both with `-Q` argument. And even if, the first worker should only read from the `myqueue`. I have no idea why it's not behaving correctly.